# Importing jars and compile them using maven

Tags: maven, jar, buildpath

We use maven to download and compile classes without importing those libraries in our build path. But when we want to use some classes from an external API, we still need to import those jars to our build path? Why is that and what's the reason for that?

Comment: I'm sorry but your question makes no sense. What exactly do you want to do? What is the problem you want to solve?

Comment: I want to know why we should import jars when we want to use java classes in our code (otherwise those external classes won't show up) even we importing those jars in maven?